# Pass configuration to logback as string instead of file

Tags: java, logging, logback

I'd like to programmatically configure logback. Calling factory methods manually is tedious and sometimes confusing task, as googling articles on this topic had shown. So I'd like simply generate xml text and pass it somehow to the logback configurator.

Is it ever possible?

---

I've read logback's documentation. It says nothing about setting context to manually created appenders, but internet articles says it is a necessary step. So I'm confused. And that is way I'd like to avoid manual creating at all.

The documentation assumes that all dirty work for building log infrastructure is done by the Joran configuration tool. So I'd like use its benefits. And pass xml text to whatever object that really done initializing work. But again, the documentation is silent about it. Common sense prompts that there should be such factory.

Comment: So that's the "simple" solution? Logback documentation is excellent, you might want to give it a looksie.

Comment: added motivation part to the question

Comment: The example in chapter 3 of the manual nearly does what you ask for. You just need to write your xml to a temporary file and pass it to Joran ... if that's an option for you.

Comment: JoranConfigurator.doConfigure is actually overloaded to receive inputstream. So, no need for temporary files. Thanks for advise